# How to Autorun a program using busybox after boot?

Tags: startup, busybox, buildroot, autostart

I am using an embedded linux with busybox. I would like to automatically run my app called "myApplication" (runlevel 5 after boot all the services are up).

What I have done so far:

- I made a script under /etc/init.d/ called S90myscript
- Then I added this line to the inittab:

`::sysinit:/etc/init.d/S90myscript`

The script contains the following:

```
! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myApplication
# Should-Start: $all
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $network $local_fs
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs
# Default-Start: 5
# Default-Stop: 0 6
# Short-Description: start myprogram at boot time
### END INIT INFO
#

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
PATH=/root:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
PROGRAMNAME="myApplication"
case "$1" in
start)
$PROGRAMNAME
;;
stop)
skill $PROGRAMNAME
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Am I missing something? Symlinks? Is what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.

1. I placed `myApplication` in `/usr/sbin/`
2. Created a symlink named myApp to the script located in `/etc/init.d/S99myAppScript`
   (notice that there is no .sh and I had to run `sudo chmod 755` on this script)
3. Added the following line at the end of `rcS` file located in `/etc/init.d/` just before the command `done`:

   ```
   myApp &
   ```

After rebooting the system, myApplication autoruns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place you app in any place. In my case full path is /root/myApplication
2. All init scripts in /etc/init.d executing one by one in numerical order. So it is good idea to set name of your script is like S99myAppScript or S98myAppScript. Because I want execute my script after all others.

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    # see about BusyBox init https://www.halolinux.us/embedded-systems/busybox-init.html
    
    # Make sure the application exists
    [ -f /root/myApplication ] || exit 0
    
    umask 077
    
    start() {
        echo "Start application:"
        /root/myApplication & # <-- Don't forget the "&" otherwise other system stuff won't start until you leave your app !!!
    }
    stop() {
        killall -q myApplication
    }
    restart() {
        stop
        start
    }
    
    case "$1" in
      start)
        start
        ;;
      stop)
        stop
        ;;
      restart|reload)
        restart
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
    esac
    
    exit $?
```

See [also](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Automatically_launch_your_application).

2. Why I can't reboot or poweroff my computer? Autorun program prevent poweroff.

Don't forget the "&" otherwise other system stuff won't start until you leave your app !!!